# linear unbiased estimator alternative to OLS

Tags: econometrics

I need to know, if anyone knows a way to calculate an unbiased linear estimator alternative to the Ordian Least Squares estimator.
Any reference or comment, is very appreciated.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: E.g., https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153348/other-unbiased-estimators-than-the-blue-ols-solution-for-linear-models/153356#153356