# Proving OLS estimator is BLUE in simplified model (deriving the variance)

Tags: regression, variance, least-squares, econometrics, blue

A model is given as $Y = \mu + u_i$ where $u_i $ $IID(0,\sigma^2)$ with a sample of $n$ observations.

I have to prove that the OLS estimator for $\mu = \frac{\sum Y_i}{n}$ is the BLUE estimator.

I derive its variance to be $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$ but now I need to show that its variance is the smallest possible for all LUE's.

I have taken a stab at it, with some help of a short solution, but I would like to understand every step of it, and also understand how to arrive at the solution.

Let $\hat{\mu}^\star = \sum w_i Y_i$ be all possible linear estimators. In order for it to be unbiased $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i$ must be equal to 1.

I start trying to simplify the variance for $\hat{\mu}^\star$

$V(\hat{\mu}^\star) = V(\mu \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i +\sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n u_i) = V(\sum w_i \cdot \sum u_i) = \sigma^2 \cdot \sum w_i^2$

The solution is to add and subtract $\frac{1}{n}$ from $\sum w_i$ to get $\sigma^2 \sum (w_i + \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n})^2$ from which it can be derived that the lowest variance is given by $w_i = \frac{1}{n}$.

The problem I am having is that I do not understand how one comes up with the adding and subtraction of $\frac{1}{n}$ without already knowing this to be the answer. I feel like I should find an expression for the variance, differentiate it and find the minimum point

Comment: So go ahead!  You have obtained an expression for the variance as a function of the $w_i.$  Differentiate, apply Lagrange multipliers to cope with the sum-to-unity constraint, and find the minimum.  If you don't know about Lagrange Multipliers, rewrite $w_n=1-(w_1+\cdots+w_{n-1}),$ plug it into the variance formula, differentiate, and find where the gradient is zero.  The merits of adding and subtracting $1/n$ should become abundantly clear when you start in on the algebra.

Comment: Thank you for a great pointer in the right direction, down the rabbit hole! As I am taking a statistics course standalone I have not yet studied pure math higher than high-school level. But after some reading up on Lagrange it is actually starting to make sense. However, if you do have the time I would really appreciate a complete solution. Anyway I do want to stress that I am very happy for this comment too.

Comment: @JonLachmann, try https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153348/other-unbiased-estimators-than-the-blue-ols-solution-for-linear-models/153356#153356