# How does ordinal regression compare to quantile regression?

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, quantiles, quantile-regression

I am familiar with ordinal regression and quantile regression at a high level, but would like a deeper understanding of the two beginning on how they differ. Can someone compare and contrast the two, perhaps with a reference(s) to an article that compares them? TIA

Comment: Quantile regression is used with quantitative variables and a lot different from ordinal regression that deals with ordinal variables. They are very different, how do you see a comparison to be made between them?

Answer (score 4):

Chapter 15 of the second edition of Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) textbook and chapter 11 of the most recent version of his [class notes](https://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) provide succinct comparisons. Either ordinal (e.g., via the `orm()` function of the [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms)) or quantile regression methods can model continuous outcomes, so a comparison does make sense.

Quoting from pages 360 and 361 of the textbook:

> Quantile regression... makes no distributional assumptions other than continuity of $Y$, while having all the usual right hand side assumptions... Using quantile regression, we directly model the median [or any other quantile] as a function of covariates so that only the $X\beta$ structure need be correct.

> A different robust semiparametric regression approach than quantile regression is the cumulative probability ordinal model...While quantile regression has no restriction in the parameters when modeling one quantile versus another, *ordinal cumulative probability models assume a connection between distributions of* $Y$ *for different* $X$. Ordinal regression even makes one less assumption than quantile regression about the distribution of $Y$ for a specific $X$: the distribution need not be continuous. (Emphasis added, to highlight a major difference from quantile regression.)

A semi-parametric ordinal regression model "contains an intercept for every unique $Y$ value less one" (legend to Table 15.1 in the textbook) and assumes a link function that provides the further association with covariates $X$ (Equation 15.2):

$$ \text{Prob}[Y \ge y_i|X]= F (\alpha_{y_i} + X\beta).$$

Typical quantile regression requires no such assumptions. There's a variant of quantile regression that restricts predictor coefficients to be the same across multiple quantiles (see footnote `b` on page 361), however, so the distinction isn't necessarily that sharp.

I understand that quantile regressions are typically [fit via linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression#Computation_of_estimates_for_regression_parameters), while ordinal regression uses maximum likelihood. That's also not such a strict distinction, however, as quantile regression can be formulated as [maximizing the likelihood for Laplace-distributed errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/397087/28500).

Comment: Thanks for the nice summary :-)   In addition, quantile regression is not very efficient for non-large N.  In the case where there is only a single binary X (the two-group problem) quantile regression is identical to stratified sample quantiles which are not very efficient.