# Non-Euclidean analogue to MSE loss

Tags: regression, machine-learning, euclidean, geometry

The most basic machine learning model called OLS uses the RSS (squared loss) or its average, mean squared error (MSE), for its loss function, which is aligned with Euclidean geometry.

What is the analogue of the MSE loss in the Riemann (non-Euclidean) world?

And is non-Euclidean based learning somehow better or empirically accurate than Euclidean learning algorithms?

Comment: The following question is related to your question, discussing other loss functions and scenarios under which minimizing MSE loss is "best": https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146077/why-not-robust-regression-everytime/146100#146100

Comment: wasn't really helpful

Comment: OLS is not a model, it is an estimation technique.

Comment: isn't that just a matter jargon. we would then have to call SVM, random forests and other machine learning models "estimation techniques". but no one does. for all they care, they more often call them algorithms

Comment: There are some clear, conventional, well-understood distinctions between models estimators, and algorithms.  Whether you consider the terminology jargon or not, it has a point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a metric space $(M, d)$ with distance function $d$, calculate the distance between the vector of true values $y$ and the predicted values $\hat{y}$. For example:

$$d_{L2}(y, \hat{y}) \propto RMSE$$

$$d_{L1}(y, \hat{y}) \propto MAE$$

Scaling by the sample size (dimension of $y$ and $\hat{y}$) does not influence the argmin of a loss function (that is, $RMSE$, $SSE$, and $MSE$ have the same argmin).

Comment: I don't see how this has anything to do with Riemann (non-Euclidean) geometry

Comment: @develarist Euclidean space is a Riemannian manifold, so what do you mean by Riemann geometry?

Comment: non-Euclidean geometry as opposed to Euclidean space

Comment: $L_1$ is not Euclidean, so $MAE$ is a non-Euclidean loss function.

Comment: so MAE is a non-Euclidean analogue to MSE? are there any others

Comment: All of the $p$-norms would be analogous in $(\mathbb{R}, d_{Lp})$, but there are other non-Euclidean norms. I gave you a general answer in an arbitrary metric space. If you don't know what a metric space is, it is a space where "distance" makes sense and follows the usual nice properties that distance should have (e.g. distance from $A$ to $B$ is the same as the distance from $B$ to $A$). If you have further questions about metric spaces or Riemannian manifolds, those would warrant separate questions, most likely on Math.SE instead of here.

Comment: in your answer, you seem to be distinguishing $d_{L1}$ from $MAE$ by saying they are inversely proportional but not the same? how so

Comment: $L1$ metric is exactly equal to $MAE$, while the $L2$ metric is off of $RMSE$ by a factor of $\sqrt{n}$ (I forget if you multiply or divide, so I will leave this as an exercise ;)). The symbol means proportional, though, not inversely proportional.

Comment: The $L_p$ metrics are not Riemannian, either.  By definition, a Riemannian manifold is locally Euclidean.